# "cannot execute binary file" error in python

Tags: python, cygwin

I keep getting the following error:

```
$ ./test.py
-bash: ./test.py: cannot execute binary file
```

when trying to run the following file in python via cygwin:

```
#!usr/bin/python
with open("input.txt") as inf:
    try:
        while True:
            latin = inf.next().strip()
            gloss = inf.next().strip()
            trans = inf.next().strip()
            process(latin, gloss, trans)
            inf.next()    # skip blank line
    except StopIteration:
        # reached end of file
        pass
from itertools import chain

def chunk(s):
    """Split a string on whitespace or hyphens"""
    return chain(*(c.split("-") for c in s.split()))

def process(latin, gloss, trans):
    chunks = zip(chunk(latin), chunk(gloss))
```

How do I fix this??

---

After taking on the below suggestions, still getting the same error.

If this helps, I tried

```
$ python ./test.py
```

and got

```
$ python ./test.py
  File "./test.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file ./test.py on line 1, but no encoding     declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Comment: try replacing #!usr/bin/python with #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: Looks like your source file has some hidden, unprintable characters in it.  What is the output of `hexdump -C test.py | head`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem. You are missing the '/' in front of usr in `#!usr/bin/python`. Your line should look like this.

`#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: try this #!/usr/bin/env python
and check files permissions : chmod +x test.py

Comment: does it run if you call with python: python test.py?

Comment: add as a second line: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: FIXED - was using notepad. remembered a friend's suggestion to use notepad2 - so I just switched & it fixed the issue. No idea why, but now I can work with it. Phew, that was an hour of frustration! >.< thanks @tigran

Comment: `notepad.exe` "Helpfully" adds a unicode "BOM", which means that the first few bytes of the file are *not* hex 0x23 0x21 (the script magic: `#!`) and instead 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF 0x23 0x21 (same thing with the byte order mark prepended).  You can control this somewhat in some versions of notepad by specifying the encoding, but you should really never use notepad.  Not ever.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to protecting the file executable, `#!/usr/bin/python` may not work. At least it has never worked for me on Red Hat or Ubuntu Linux. Instead, I have put this in my Python files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I don't know how this works on Windows platforms.